# how to print only one data record from duplicate foreign ids in the laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5.6 and I have multiple images in my uploads table with related to vehicle_id, as foreign key like this,

```
uploads table
id          fileName        vehicle_id
1            1.jpg               1
2            2.jpg               1
3            3.jpg               1
4            4.jpg               1
5            28.png              2
6            28.png              2
7            29.png              2
8            30.png              3
9            31.png              3
10           56.png              3
```

The vehicle table hasMany relationship with the uploads table,

```
public function thumbnail() {
    return $this->hasMany(Upload::class)->orderByDesc('id');
}
```

VehicleController is,

```
public function index()
    {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::with('thumbnail')->get();
        return view('vechicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
}
```

and data showing index.blade.php file is,

```
@if($vehicles)
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
{{$vehicle->district}}
{{$vehicle->town}}
{{$vehicle->brand}}
{{$vehicle->model}}

<hr>

 <tr>
  @foreach($vehicle->thumbnail as $aaa)
                    <img src="/images/{{ $aaa->resized_name }}">
                    @endforeach

                </tr>


@endforeach
@endif
```

but still in my view file I can show multiple images which related to vehicle_id (not only show only one image regarding to vehicle_id), then, how can I show only one image to relevant each vehicle_id?

Answer (score 0):

By `Constraining Eager Loading` your relationship and limiting the results from it.

replace the line

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('thumbnail')->get();
```

By the following

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with([
    'thumbnail' => function ($q) {
        $q->limit(1);
    }
])->get();
```

You may also use the [`first`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) method instead of limit,

another approach is to create a new relationship with the limited thumbnail, in your vehicle model add a new relationship like though

```
public function oneThumb () { // or whatever your method name
    return $this->hasMany(Upload::class)->orderByDesc('id')->limit(1);
}
```

Comment: in this way i can see only one image from my upload table not showing other ids images

Comment: `then, how can I show only one image to relevant each vehicle_id` ? that's what you was asking about

Comment: I mean I need only one image for each vehicle_id, as an example in above uploads table I need only one image for vehicle_id '1' and one image for vehicle_id '2' etc...

Comment: this happens in the both solutions in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There´s three things you can do:

1. Limit your query to only one result from each id,
2. Change your table structure and add a "featured_image" column for you to identify which relevant image you want to show on your view.
3. Group the results by vehicle_id so you only get one image per vehicle_id.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I removed that since it will output only one row from the table (not from each vehicle_id), the second option is the most suitable of doing it, but the third one will probably be the fastest way to achieve what you want, although you won´t have control if you want to show a specific image.

Comment: Try this $vehicles = Vehicle::with('thumbnail')->groupBy('vehicle_id')->get();

Comment: occured tthis error msg **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vehicle_id' in 'group statement' (SQL: select * from `vehicles` group by `vehicle_id`)**

Comment: Sorry, this is the one:
$vehicles = Vehicle::with(['thumbnail' => function ($query) { $query->groupBy('vehicle_id', asc); }])->get();

Comment: now got **Use of undefined constant asc - assumed 'asc'**

Comment: Just, change asc to 'asc' :/